# How to see the unique active devices all time per Flurry API?

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

I would like to get the number of (unique) active devices of all time for my apps via Flurry API. With "unique active device" I mean any device which has started the app (at least once - so counted only once) since time being.

The Definition of Flurry of "Active User" is 
*An active device is defined as a device that has had at least one session with your app during a given time period (hours, days, weeks, months). If a device launches more than one session during a given period, it will only be counted once.*.

The biggest time period mentioned here is **month** and so I understand
*When the same device starts a session in month 1 but also in month 2 it will be counted twice.* Right? And that wouldn't be the correct number.

So is that requested number anywhere *available* in Flurry and via API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The App Summary dashboard has the option to set the time period to "All Time". One of the metrics is for Active Devices. The number there is the number of unique users across all time.

It is not available via API. The metrics API has a limit of 90 days.